# Histogram plotting in Pandas for a dataframe with single and 58000 columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, image-processing, histogram

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image

hlack_img = Image.open("Henrietta_Lacks.jpg")
hlack_arr = np.array(hlack_img)
print(hlack_arr.shape) # (290,200)
features = np.reshape(hlack_img, (290*200))
hlack_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([features]), index=['hlack'])
print(hlack_df)
hlack_df.hist()
```

I am trying to plot this in a histogram to see the pixel distributions, which is taking forever. The dataframe has 1 row, 58000 columns. Since there are so many columns, the histogram plotting is taking time, I believe or is there some other reason?. Any help is really appreciated. What's the best way to plot it in a histogram that shows the distribution of pixel?

Comment: what if you try to plot 58000 rows instead of columns by transforming the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

For this plot alone you actually don't really need pandas.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

hlack_img = Image.open("images/color_wheel.jpg")
hlack_arr = np.array(hlack_img)
print(hlack_arr.shape) # (290,200)
plt.hist(hlack_arr.reshape(-1))
```

`reshape(-1)` flatten your array to a (58000,) array. Plotted like this you get the pixels as bins on x-axis and their distribution on y-axis